# python function giving undesired result

Tags: python, function

I'm a newbie to programming, and I have been learning and trying the basics as I go through, but I'm stuck with the code below and can't really figure out what's wrong with it.. I'm not getting the desired output.

```
def sho(cards):
    global num 
    num = 0
    for card in cards:
        print(card)
        if 0 < card < 7:
            num+=1
        else:
            num-=1
            return num


ace = [1, 6 ]
print(sho(ace))
```

Comment: Welcome. You should add "desired output" into your question.

Comment: You probably want to unindent `return num` it returns none if the else isn't hit and returns the first time the else hits.

Comment: What do you expect? (num shouldn't be global, the return probably should not be indented as shown in your code)

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. It makes it hard for people to help you. You can make the code format nicely by indenting 4 characters.

Comment: lol, just to put the return statement out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
def sho(cards):
    global num
    num = 0
    for card in cards:
        print(card)
        if 0 < card < 7:
            num+=1
        else:
            num-=1
    return num


ace = [1, 6 ]
print(sho(ace))
```

Output:

```
1
6
2
```

Comment: Yes. It definitely is. Thanks

Comment: Cool, upvote and accept the answer if this answer has helped you

Answer (score 0):

```
def sho(cards):
    num = 0
    for card in cards:
        print(card)
        if 0 < card < 7:
            num+=1
        else:
            num-=1
    return num
ace = [1,6,8,9]
sho(ace)
```

try above code lines. it should return you output = 1, which I feel you are looking for. Let me know if you desire different output in this case.